# While trying to start react app i am facing the below error and it is not compiling why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I got a notification in vs-code to activate tc(type-script) and i activated it. After that when i am trying to run basic example app(npx create-react-app my-app) given in the react docs, i am facing the below error. Can any one tell the best way to overcome this issue?

```
./src/index.js 1:77
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:77)
    File was processed with these loaders:
     * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
     * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
    You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
    > $RefreshRuntime$ = require('E:/ReactJS preparation(GD)/ReactProject with API's/my-app/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');
    | $RefreshSetup$(module.id);
    |
```

Comment: Did you try to restart VS?

Comment: Yep...i fully uninstalled VScode and installed again but i am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be in the way you named your folder, including spaces and apostrophe (the ' in API's).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Guillermo is right, you are seeing this error because of the path of the file:

`E:/ReactJS preparation(GD)/ReactProject with API`

the spaces are preventing the file to be accessed correctly. I had a similar issue with ' in the name.

Comment: Yes, it what I said "Guillermo is right" and added some clarification to help. Why is that not ok? (I also upvoted his answer).

Comment: he says 'it could be' and then not much else. I wanted to confirm that for me that was the issue and give clearer steps to fix (particularly for newbies and for people scrolling for answers with steps and code like myself).